# iPhone: .ipa PNG Files

Tags: iphone, png, ipa

how can I open the PNG Files from iPhone Applications (.ipa)?

An example: I download an App in iTunes App Store, click on "Show in finder" to find the XXX.ipa File, I rename it to XXX.zip, extract the files, open the directory, but I am not able to open the PNG files. How can I open them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend http://www.pragmaticcode.com/crunch/.

Comment: Whow, your recommendation (Crunch) is really very good. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

PNG's are crushed when put into .ipa files.  You need to uncrush them.

Here are two tools to do so:

QuickLook Plugin PngUncrush.qlgenerator found at: http://castelliweb.com/blog/2010/05/24/quicklook-plugins-for-mac/

or a command line tool iPhonePNG found at: http://www.newsfirex.com/blog/?p=176